# Find most recent Monday for a dataframe

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe object, and among the fields in it, I have a dates:

```
df$dates
```

I need to add a column which is 'Week Starting', i.e.

```
df[,'WeekStart']= manipulation
```

Where the week start is the date of the Monday of that week. i.e.: today is Thursday 24/09/15, would have an entry as '21-Sept'. Next thursday, 01/10/15, would be '28-Sept'.

I see that there is a `weekday()` function which will convert a day into a week-day, but how can I deal with this `most recent monday`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples:

```
dates <-(Sys.Date()+1:30)
week.starts <- as.Date(sapply (dates, function(d) { return (d + (-6 - as.POSIXlt(d)$wday %% -7 ))}), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

and running as

```
d <- data.frame(dataes=dates, monday=week.starts)
```

gives

```
       dataes     monday
1  2015-09-25 2015-09-21
2  2015-09-26 2015-09-21
3  2015-09-27 2015-09-21
4  2015-09-28 2015-09-28
5  2015-09-29 2015-09-28
6  2015-09-30 2015-09-28
7  2015-10-01 2015-09-28
8  2015-10-02 2015-09-28
9  2015-10-03 2015-09-28
10 2015-10-04 2015-09-28
11 2015-10-05 2015-10-05
12 2015-10-06 2015-10-05
13 2015-10-07 2015-10-05
14 2015-10-08 2015-10-05
15 2015-10-09 2015-10-05
16 2015-10-10 2015-10-05
17 2015-10-11 2015-10-05
18 2015-10-12 2015-10-12
19 2015-10-13 2015-10-12
20 2015-10-14 2015-10-12
21 2015-10-15 2015-10-12
22 2015-10-16 2015-10-12
23 2015-10-17 2015-10-12
24 2015-10-18 2015-10-12
25 2015-10-19 2015-10-19
26 2015-10-20 2015-10-19
27 2015-10-21 2015-10-19
28 2015-10-22 2015-10-19
29 2015-10-23 2015-10-19
30 2015-10-24 2015-10-19
```

Similar approach, example:

```
# data
d <- data.frame(date = as.Date( c("20/09/2015","24/09/2015","28/09/2015","01/10/2015"), "%d/%m/%Y"))

# get monday
d$WeekStart <- d$date - 6 - (as.POSIXlt(d$date)$wday %% -7)

d
# result
#         date  WeekStart
# 1 2015-09-20 2015-09-14
# 2 2015-09-24 2015-09-21
# 3 2015-09-28 2015-09-28
# 4 2015-10-01 2015-09-28
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
Rscript master_func.r
Error in as.Date.numeric(sapply(newdf$dates, function(d) { : 
  'origin' must be supplied
Calls: main_loop -> as.Date -> as.Date.numeric
Execution halted

newdf[,'dates'] looks something like:

"2015-10-04" "2015-10-05" "2015-10-06" "2015-10-07" "2015-10-08"
"2015-10-09" "2015-10-10" "2015-10-11" "2015-10-12" "2015-10-13"

Comment: See edit above. I was using `xts`, now changed to use base packages(added `origin`)

Comment: Will the origin generalise, I.e. if I have data pre 1970?

Comment: It will  "Internally, Date objects are stored as the number of days since January 1, 1970, using negative numbers for earlier dates.".

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` approach with the function `strftime`.

```
df$Week.Start <- dates-abs(1-as.numeric(strftime(df$dates, "%u")))
```

This can be a one-liner but we'll create a few variables to see what's happening. The `%u` format pattern for dates returns the day of the week as a single decimal number. We can convert that number to `numeric` and subtract the distance from our dates. We can then subtract that vector from our date column.

```
day_of_week <- as.numeric(strftime(df$dates, "%u"))
day_diff <- abs(1-day_of_week)
df$Week.Start <- dates-day_diff
#        dates Week.Start
# 1 2042-10-22 2042-10-20
# 2 2026-08-14 2026-08-10
# 3 2018-11-23 2018-11-19
# 4 2017-08-21 2017-08-21
# 5 2022-05-26 2022-05-23
# 6 2037-05-27 2037-05-25
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(7)
all_dates <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+10000, by="days")
dates <- sample(all_dates, 20)
df <- data.frame(dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just subtracting from the dates the number of days required to get to the previous Monday? e.g if your data is

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2000-07-12", "2005-02-19", "2010-09-01"))
weekdays(dates)
# [1] "Wednesday" "Saturday"  "Wednesday"
```

then you can compare this to a vector

```
wdays <- setNames(0:6, c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

and subtract the required number of days from each date, ie

```
dates - wdays[weekdays(dates)]
#   Wednesday     Saturday    Wednesday 
#"2000-07-10" "2005-02-14" "2010-08-30"
```

will give the dates of the Monday preceding each date in `dates`. To test:

```
weekdays(dates - wdays[weekdays(dates)])
#Wednesday  Saturday Wednesday 
# "Monday"  "Monday"  "Monday"
```

Everything can be written also in one line as

```
dates - match(weekdays(dates), c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
   "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")) + 1
#"2000-07-10" "2005-02-14" "2010-08-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[1] <-as.Date("2016-08-20")
```

*Finding Next day (Here "Monday")*

```
a[1] + match("Monday",weekdays(seq(a[1]+1, a[1]+6,"days")))
```

"2016-08-22"

*Finding Last Day (Here "Friday")*

```
a[1] + (match("Friday",weekdays(seq(a[1]+1, a[1]+6,"days")))-7)
```

"2016-08-19"

Answer (score 0):

A simple base-R way if your dates are properly coded as date class in R: `as.Date(unclass(dates)-unclass(dates)%%7-3)`. You unclass it do get number of days since 1970-01-01. Then subtract remainder from division on 7 (day of the week!). Then subtract 3 because 1970-01-01 was Thursday –

Also you can group your data by week, and then create a column of "minimal date of that week". Here is how to do it in `data.table` package:

```
df=data.table(df)
df[,lastMonday:=min(dates),by=.(week(dates))]
```

It should work if you dont have spaces in dates.
Also, in some locales week starts with sunday, so you should be careful.
And you will need additional grouping variable, if your dates span for more than a year

Comment: My dates unfortunately span decades. If I go down this route can I easily re-cast it back into the DataFrame format? Is there any reason to go to data.table? Thanks!

Comment: if dates span decades, then just add a year to your grouping variable: `df[,lastMonday:=min(dates),by=.(week(dates),year(dates)]`. As for packages, `dplyr` and `data.table` are most commonly used for this kind of tasks. It is also possible in base R, but requires lots of splitting|sapplying and other stuff like that which is just not convenient. Data.table is still technically a data.frame, so the format will stay the same

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'd like to ideally stick to base R for the sake of the task at hand. I'll try to see if there is another way to tackle this problem and if not I'll have to take a step back and think about it. Unfortunately this is mandatory output so I do need to deliver it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nearest any day and hour to the current date, use this function:

```
dayhour <- function(day,hour){
   k <- as.Date(Sys.time())+day-as.numeric(format(strptime(Sys.time(),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format ='%u'))
   dh <- format(strptime(paste(k,hour), format="%Y-%m-%d %H"), format="%A %H")
   return(dh)
}
```

For the weekdays use 0 to 6 as day argument for sunday to saturday respectively:

```
> dayhour(0,17)
[1] "Sunday 17"
```